# tikz node color resets

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes

I am having trouble with node colors resetting after specifying a color for a single word.  I have the following MWE where I have the string `3\\ 4\\ 5\\ 6` in which I have specified that `4` be `\red{}` and I need the other remaining *words* to be a secondary color, in this example I have chosen blue. Please note that for the purpose of this question the string definition should not be altered in any way. I read similar questions about a bug in tikz or xcolor from a few years ago related to boxes, but I am unsure if this issue is related or not.

[image: the 5 and 6 should also be colored blue]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,calc}


\NewDocumentCommand{\size}{m}{%
    \fontsize{#1}{#1}\selectfont%
}%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\red}{m}{%
    {\color{red}#1}%
}%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mystring}{}{%
    3\\ \red{4}\\ 5\\ 6%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
    \node[draw, align=center, text=blue, font=\bfseries\size{80}] at (0,0) {\mystring};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
    \node[draw, align=center, font=\bfseries\size{80}] at (0,0) {\color{blue} \mystring};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Observation, It should be noted that if the color red is not specified, the first column will all be blue, where in the second test only the first letter is blue.

Comment: TikZ resets color at each newline...

Comment: Note: here, in the first tikzpicture, all the letters are blue except the second (with TeXLive 2021).

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. I ran `brew upgrade mactex` and an hour later with TexLive 2021 I get desired results. Although it seems to have deleted by 2019 version which is disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you consider using a `matrix`? This way you can fix the color for every row with independence of the matrix general color.

The syntax for `\mystring` keeps `\\` between rows. You can select the color for a row with a `row x/.style` on the matrix options or fix it inside the list or rows like in `\mystringwithcolorsinside`.

A `TiKZ` matrix finishes with `\\`. I've added it after `\mystring` command, but you could insert them as last list characters.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,calc,matrix}


\NewDocumentCommand{\size}{m}{%
    \fontsize{#1}{#1}\selectfont%
}%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\red}{m}{%
    {\color{red}#1}%
}%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mystring}{}{%
    3\\ 4\\ 5\\ 6%
}%

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\mystringiwthcolorsinside}{}{%
    3\\|[text=green]| 4\\ 5\\ 6%
}%

\tikzset{mycolumn/.style={matrix, matrix of nodes, draw, inner sep=0pt, 
    text=blue, font=\bfseries\size{80}, nodes={align=center, inner sep=.3333em},
    row 2/.style={text=red}}}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
    \node[mycolumn] at (0,0) {\mystring\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]
    \node[mycolumn] at (0,0) {\mystringiwthcolorsinside\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]